# Unable to store relative pathnames to data sources in ArcGIS Publisher

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-publisher

The Publisher extension in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 isn't saving the relative data source for our enterprise geodatabase layers. The data sources are referencing the enterprise geodatabase directly rather than in the specified location set in the Data Packaging.

ESRI tutorial Link:
[How To: Create a PMF that can be opened in ArcMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6mVN.png)

ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 - Map Document Properties

[image: ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1]

[image]

[image]